YA (?) Book about a girl who had magic powers and was fleeing with her brother
I think I read this book in middle school.  A young girl (or late teen) is fleeing with her brother.  She has magic powers and she does not think he does.  I am pretty sure she can talk with animals and has some sort of animal that guarded them? They came across a protected castle? villa?  And they stay there with a man who also has magic powers.
In the end, the brother does end up having magic powers (like of charisma) and is able to sway people to his side.  He betrays the sister and leaves to maybe join the bad person they were running from at the beginning of the book?
It always felt like it might be a series, but I could only ever find that one book.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were in middle school; approximately what year was this?

Do you remember how you read it (eBook, paperback, hardback, etc)? Do you remember what they were fleeing from?
